# Resize uiview along with rotation of uiimageview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview

I have one uiimageview which is added as subview in uiview. frame for uiimageview is uiview's bounds. I am using this uiview just to show the border. Now when i rotate the imageview, only image view is rotated, but while rotating extra part beyond uiview is getting clipped. How can i resize uiview along with image views rotation.

This is my code. I have done what you have said but view is not resizing

```
 - (void)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {



float rotation = angle + -recognizer.rotation;

recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-rotation);


if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    angle = rotation;

}  

    CGFloat diagonal = sqrt( recognizer.view.bounds.size.width*recognizer.view.bounds.size.width + recognizer.view.bounds.size.height*recognizer.view.bounds.size.height );

    CGRect rect = view.frame;
    rect.origin.x -= ((rect.size.width-diagonal)/2);
    rect.origin.y -= ((rect.size.height-diagonal)/2);
    rect.size.width = diagonal;
    rect.size.height = diagonal;
   view.frame = rect;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the diagonal of the UIImageView.

```
CGFloat diagonal = sqrt( imageview.size.width*imageview.size.width + imageview.size.height*imageview.size.height );
```

Then set it to the UIView's frame.

```
CGRect rect = view.frame;
rect.origin.x -= ((rect.size.width-diagonal)/2);
rect.origin.y -= ((rect.size.height-diagonal)/2);
rect.size.width = diagonal;
rect.size.height = diagonal;
view.frame = rect;
```

**Edit:**
In the following line, you may not need the bounds size.

```
   CGFloat diagonal = sqrt( recognizer.view.bounds.size.width*recognizer.view.bounds.size.width + recognizer.view.bounds.size.height*recognizer.view.bounds.size.height );
```

Try as the following:

```
CGFloat diagonal = sqrt( recognizer.view.frame.size.width*recognizer.view.frame.size.width + recognizer.view.frame.size.height*recognizer.view.frame.size.height );
```

Comment: But what abut the origin of uiview , it should also be changed with rotation.

Comment: No, in my code the origin will be the same. Just I have increased its width and height. If you want to move the origin also, you can.

Comment: I have updated my answer such that the origin would also be moved.

Comment: I have updated my question with code .Can you tell me what is wrong.

Comment: But here the diagonal length will be same for all angles. I want to resize the uiview according to the angle change.

Comment: Oh sorry, I have missed the `frame`. Plz check now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6582/discussion-between-prerna-and-aadhira)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like..

```
     float minX = MIN(self.imgDisplayImage.frame.origin.x,self.imgDisplayImage.frame.origin.x+self.imgDisplayImage.frame.size.width);
     float maxX = MAX(self.imgDisplayImage.frame.origin.x,self.imgDisplayImage.frame.origin.x+self.imgDisplayImage.frame.size.width);


     float minY = MIN(self.imgDisplayImage.frame.origin.y,self.imgDisplayImage.frame.origin.y+self.imgDisplayImage.frame.size.height);
     float maxY = MAX(self.imgDisplayImage.frame.origin.y,self.imgDisplayImage.frame.origin.y+self.imgDisplayImage.frame.size.height);


     float finalWidth = maxX-minX; 
     float finalHeight = maxY-minY; 


     CGPoint initialCenter = self.center;
     self.frame = CGRectMake(minX, minY,finalWidth,finalHeight);

     CGPoint newCenter;
     newCenter.x = initialCenter.x+minX;
     newCenter.y = initialCenter.y+minY;

     self.center = newCenter;


     CGPoint imgCenter = self.imgDisplayImage.center;


     self.imgDisplayImage.center = CGPointMake(imgCenter.x-minX, imgCenter.y-minY);
```

Comment: Would you consider explaining that so someone finding this answer can make sense of it?